# AWS Lambda deployed on LocalStack always receiving null as InputObject

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, quarkus, localstack

I deployed on LocalStack a Quarkus Java Native Lambda and assigned a function URL to it,
here's my handler Code:

```
package it.example.quarkusnativelambdatemplate;

import jakarta.inject.Named;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Named("template-lambda")
@Slf4j
public class TemplateLambda implements RequestHandler<InputObject, OutputObject> {

    @Override
    public OutputObject handleRequest(InputObject input, Context context) {
        log.debug("[TemplateLambda.handleRequest] [input.name = {} | input.greeting = {}", input.getName(), input.getGreeting());

        //My Lambda logic here....

        OutputObject outputObject = new OutputObject();
        outputObject.setResult(String.format("%s %s", input.getGreeting(), input.getName()));
        return outputObject;
    }
}
```

Here's my InputObject:

```
package it.example.quarkusnativelambdatemplate;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
public class InputObject {
    private String name;
    private String greeting;
}
```

Here's the curl I'm trying:

```
curl --location 'http://yfer9nmb4svqec0fv06ldtj1sfr55la6.lambda-url.us-east-1.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "name": "Francesco",
    "greeting": "Ciao"
}'
```

And here's the log result on LocalStack:

```
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
__ ____ __ _____ ___ __ ____ ______
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
--/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
-/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
2024-01-27 10:43:30,741 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-native-lambda-template 1.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 3.6.7) started in 0.003s.
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
2024-01-27 10:43:30,741 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
2024-01-27 10:43:30,741 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [amazon-lambda, cdi]
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
START RequestId: ae5580b8-e54a-4e30-ac3d-a1dd35d92527 Version: $LATEST
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
2024-01-27 10:43:30,746 DEBUG [it.exa.qua.TemplateLambda] (Lambda Thread (NORMAL)) [TemplateLambda.handleRequest] [input.name = null | input.greeting = null
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
END RequestId: ae5580b8-e54a-4e30-ac3d-a1dd35d92527
2024-01-27 11:43:30
[2024/01/27/[$LATEST]f952ee94b9ae43ec69f82ab654f4017b]
REPORT RequestId: ae5580b8-e54a-4e30-ac3d-a1dd35d92527 Duration: 0.94 ms Billed Duration: 1 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB
```

As you can see `[TemplateLambda.handleRequest] [input.name = null | input.greeting = null`
the input object is simply not filled with the JSON payload I'm passing.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue using the `APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent` instead of the `InputObject` argument for the `handleRequest` method:

```
@Named("template-lambda")
@Slf4j
public class TemplateLambda implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent, OutputObject> {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public OutputObject handleRequest(APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent event, Context context) {
        String body = event.getBody();
        log.debug("[TemplateLambda.handleRequest START] [body = {}]", body);
        InputObject input = new Gson().fromJson(body, InputObject.class);

        //My Lambda logic here....

        OutputObject outputObject = new OutputObject();
        outputObject.setResult(String.format("%s %s", input.getGreeting(), input.getName()));
        //outputObject.setResult(String.format("%s %s", input.getGreeting(), input.getName()));
        log.info("[TemplateLambda.handleRequest STOP] [outputObject.result = {}]", outputObject.getResult());
        return outputObject;
    }
}
```

I parsed the JSON body using the GSON library to the `InputObject` object, that's it. To compile natively I had to put `@RegisterForReflection` annotated on the `InputObject` class